# Pfaffian of the antisymmetric matrix whose all upper diagonal entries are 1

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant, pfaffian

What is the pfaffian of $n\times n$ antisymmetric matrix whose all upper diagonal entries are 1? Is there any method to compute?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you mean that the *strictly upper triangular* part of the skew-symmetric matrix $A$ contains only ones. If we define a matrix $P$ as follows, then $P^TAP$ has a very nice form:
$$
P=\pmatrix{1&-1\\ &\ddots&\ddots\\ &&\ddots&-1\\ &&&1},
\quad P^TAP=\pmatrix{0&1\\ -1&\ddots&\ddots\\ &\ddots&\ddots&1\\ &&-1&0}.
$$
You may now obtain the value of $\operatorname{pf}(A)$ easily by using some well-known properties of Pfaffian (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pfaffian) for some such properties).